# Neovim lsp auto-fix / fix-current?

Tags: neovim, language-server-protocol

I was looking for a solution similar to CoC's [coc-fix-current](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/blob/release/doc/coc.txt#L2813) but using native lsp for Neovim 0.5 but I did not find such thing in the [documentation](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lsp.html), is there any way to achieve this through other method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of neovim 0.8, thanks to [this PR](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/18221), there's an `apply` boolean which does just that.

To make sure you only apply relevant fixes, you can use the `filter` attribute and look for the "prefered" fixes.

Here's what I've put in my config :

```lua
local opts = { noremap=true, silent=true }

local function quickfix()
    vim.lsp.buf.code_action({
        filter = function(a) return a.isPreferred end,
        apply = true
    })
end

vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>qf', quickfix, opts)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and by hacking up the code that the `telescope.nvim` plugin uses to list and run code actions, came up with this monstrosity:

```lua
local function run_action(action, offse)
    if action.edit or type(action.command) == "table" then
        if action.edit then
            vim.lsp.util.apply_workspace_edit(action.edit, offse)
        end
        if type(action.command) == "table" then
            vim.lsp.buf.execute_command(action.command)
        end
    else
        vim.lsp.buf.execute_command(action)
    end
end

local function do_action(action, client)
    if
      not action.edit
      and client
      and type(client.resolved_capabilities.code_action) == "table"
      and client.resolved_capabilities.code_action.resolveProvider
    then
        client.request("codeAction/resolve", action, function(err, real)
            if err then
                return
            end
            if real then
                run_action(real, client.offset_encoding)
            else
                run_action(action, client.offset_encoding)
            end
        end)
    else
        run_action(action, client.offset_encoding) 
    end
end

return function() 
    local params = vim.lsp.util.make_range_params() -- get params for current position
    params.context = {
        diagnostics = vim.lsp.diagnostic.get_line_diagnostics(),
        only = {"quickfix"}
    }

    local results, err = vim.lsp.buf_request_sync(
        0, -- current buffer
        "textDocument/codeAction", -- get code actions
        params,
        900
    )

    if err then return end

    if not results or vim.tbl_isempty(results) then
        print "No quickfixes!"
        return
    end

    -- we have an action!
    for cid, resp in pairs(results) do
        if resp.result then
            for _, result in pairs(resp.result) do 
                -- this is the first action, run it
                do_action(result, vim.lsp.get_client_by_id(cid))
                return
            end
        end 
    end

    print "No quickfixes!"
end
```

Since it's lua, you'll need to place it in a `.lua` file somewhere that `nvim` searches for modules (for example, as `~/.config/nvim/lua/lsp_fixcurrent.lua`) and then bind to `:lua require("lsp_fixcurrent")()`

Comment: you sir made my day, it may look hacky but works very well, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for: `vim.lsp.buf.code_action()`?

Comment: As far as I understand this is providing a valid answer to the question. Using this function I was able to fix fixable lsp errors.

Comment: While this opens a window to select a code action, it's not actually what I was searching for, i'm searching for a feature like coc's "coc-fix-current" which automatically selects the correct code action upon function invoke, I appreciate the answer anyways.

Comment: In my case I'm using ccls for c++ as lsp server, and I have cases where coc's `coc-fix-current` fixes the issue and the native lsp `vim.lsp.buf.code_action({"quickfix"})` claims there is no code-action, not sure what is going on here (maybe bug, or just something I don't understand). Also haven't tried to accepted answer yet.

Comment: As for Rust, it seems like `coc-fix-current` will change code to what `cargo clippy` says, but `vim.lsp.buf.code_action()` won't. :(

Answer (score 1):

mincrmatt12 answer, updated for newer neovim (0.8?) which complains `client.resolved_capabilities` should not be used.

```lua
local function run_action(action, offse)
    if action.edit or type(action.command) == "table" then
        if action.edit then
            vim.lsp.util.apply_workspace_edit(action.edit, offse)
        end
        if type(action.command) == "table" then
            vim.lsp.buf.execute_command(action.command)
        end
    else
        vim.lsp.buf.execute_command(action)
    end
end

local function do_action(action, client)
    if
        not action.edit
        and client
        and type(client.server_capabilities) == "table"
        and client.server_capabilities.resolveProvider
    then
        client.request("codeAction/resolve", action, function(err, real)
            if err then
                return
            end
            if real then
                run_action(real, client.offset_encoding)
            else
                run_action(action, client.offset_encoding)
            end
        end)
    else
        run_action(action, client.offset_encoding)
    end
end

return function()
    local params = vim.lsp.util.make_range_params() -- get params for current position
    params.context = {
        diagnostics = vim.lsp.diagnostic.get_line_diagnostics(),
        only = { "quickfix" },
    }

    local results, err = vim.lsp.buf_request_sync(
        0, -- current buffer
        "textDocument/codeAction", -- get code actions
        params,
        900
    )

    if err then
        return
    end

    if not results or vim.tbl_isempty(results) then
        print("No quickfixes!")
        return
    end

    -- we have an action!
    for cid, resp in pairs(results) do
        if resp.result then
            for _, result in pairs(resp.result) do
                -- this is the first action, run it
                do_action(result, vim.lsp.get_client_by_id(cid))
                return
            end
        end
    end

    print("No quickfixes!")
end
```